# Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443 http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local

Tags: kubernetes, next.js, microservices, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl

**kubectl get namespace**

```
default           Active   3h33m
ingress-nginx     Active   3h11m
kube-node-lease   Active   3h33m
kube-public       Active   3h33m
kube-system       Active   3h33m
```

**kubectl get services -n ingress-nginx**

```
NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   
PORT(S)                      AGE
ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.102.205.190   localhost     80:31378/TCP,443:31888/TCP   3h12m
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.103.97.209    <none>        443/TCP                      3h12m
```

When I am making the request from nextjs getInitialProps `http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local/api/users/currentuser` then its throwing an error  `Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:443`.

```
 LandingPage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  if (typeof window === "undefined") {
    const { data } = await axios.get(
      "http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.cluster.local/api/users/currentuser",
      {
        headers: {
          Host: "ticketing.dev",
        },
      }
    );

    return data;
  } else {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/users/currentuser");

    return data;
  }
};
```

**My auth.deply.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata: 
  name: auth-depl
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector: 
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: sajeebxn/auth
          env:
            - name: MONGO_URI
              value: 'mongodb://tickets-mongo-srv:27017/auth'
            - name: JWT_KEY
              valueFrom:
                secretKeyRef:
                  name: jwt-secret
                  key: JWT_KEY
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth-srv
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

**And my ingress-srv.yaml**

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - ticketing.dev
    # secretName: e-ticket-secret
  rules:
  - host: ticketing.dev
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /api/users/?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: auth-srv
            port:
              number: 3000          
      - path: /?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: client-srv
            port:
              number: 3000
```

Comment: Were you able to figure this out ?  I am getting. Error: getaddrinfo EAI_AGAIN ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx.svc.local

looks like DNS issue

Comment: @j10 nope. I'm completely stuck on it.

Answer (score 0):

Try using http://ingress-nginx-controller.ingress-nginx/api/users/currentuser.

This worked for me